# Gatling: How can I get response time per user per request in the report?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have configured the Gatling tool with Maven and is working fine for me, however, being a new starter, I am not sure how to get the precise data in the report.

My requirement is to get each VU request/response time in the report, however, by default Gatling only provides total request and reponses in the report.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can add user info (contained in the session - userid) In the request name defined in the first exec and extract any metric from this in grafana, could this work for you?